# Off target absolutely positioned elements in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have a bunch of absolutely positioned elements being generated into a div through javascript.
The positioning of each element differs 2px vertically. IE however adds an extra vertical pixel every 3 elements, then one every 2 elements and then back every 3 elements.

Wait, A pic explains it:

[image: What IE does]

I have coloured the back behaving blocks in red, the correct ones in green.
Chrome renders it correctly (and so does Firefox):

[image: What Chrome does]

When I use the IE developer tools, I can see that the CSS is set correctly:

[image: CSS]

I've tried adding `zoom:1` to the elements, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The code to add the elements is this:

```
var element = document.createElement("a");
element.style.fontSize = "6pt";
element.style.width = "20px";
element.style.height = "20px";
element.style.position = "absolute";
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
element.style.zoom = "1";
element.style.display = "block";
var tofs = (columns * 2 + r * 20 - (c * 2));
var lofs = (c * 14 + (r + offset) * 9);
trace(c + "," + r + ": " + lofs + "," + tofs);
element.style.top = tofs + "px";
element.style.left = lofs + "px";
element.style.textIndent = "-10000px";
element.style.overflow = "hidden";
element.innerText = t;
element.selectable = "no";
setBackgroundForSeat(t, element);
target.append(element);
```

I have tried adjusting the offset every 3 then 2 elements when IE is detected, but that doesn't work: the actual visual difference to the next element becomes `1px` instead of the desired `2px` (where without the hack it's `3px`).

I have run out of ideas. Anybody?

**Update:** Here's a JS fiddle with the behaviour described. http://jsfiddle.net/uGHDh/5/

Comment: That's weird. Try calculating the `bottom` position too, *maybe* setting both `top` and `bottom` will make IE behave differently?

Comment: Although 6pt < 20px, try setting the line-height and/or font-size to something small. A jsfiddle would really help too.

Comment: It's not the font size. I tried fiddling with that, to no avail.

Comment: I'll see if I can whip up a JS fiddle.

Comment: I added a JS fiddle example.

Comment: Which version of IE, because your JSFiddle example looks fine in IE9

Comment: I've tested using IE10 in Win8 (also tried the compatibility views).

Answer (score 0):

I know the IE toolbar is telling you it's setting the CSS correctly, but it might be lying about the actual values. From your code it looks like you will be getting floating point values, and it seems like IE is producing rounding errors when it draws out the objects.

You could try casting the pixel values to an integar before using them, but that might product unwanted results in all the browsers.

Comment: I'm not getting floating point values. `r` and `c` are ints ("row" and "column"). So is `columns` and `offset`. So that's not the problem.